# Remove outdated comound indexes that change often (increment)

Tags: mongodb

I have a user document with structure like this

```
email: string
version: number
username: string
```

And this user collection has following indexes

```
collection.createIndex({email: 1}, {unique: true})
collection.createIndex({email: 1, version: 1})
```

First index ensures that email is unique and second one allows for more efficient lookup and updates when queries like this one are executed

```
collection.updateOne({email: "...", version: 2}, data)
```

My concern is this - every time user document is updated it's version is incremented. Does this mean that there is now an index for each combination of email-version? Which means that with time such index will occupy a lot of resources.
Is it possible to make mongo remove old email-version index once version changes (as it can only be incremented)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexes are implemented on the storage engine side. Mongo just uses them. In case of wiredtiger, it's b-tree for regular indexes.
Any document update which changes indexed field results with deletion of previous node in the tree and insertion of the new one.